# Unable to test a component with useLocation hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-router-dom

I have a `Header`component as follows:

```
const Header = () => {
    const data = useDataContext().header;

    return <div data-testid="header" className="w-full h-[80px] bg-white">
        <div className="h-1 bg-green-400 w-full"/>
        <div className="flex items-center w-full h-[80px] shadow-sm">
            <div className="flex items-center flex-1 h-full">
                <Navigation applications={data.apps}/>
            </div>
            <div className="flex items-center pl-4 h-full">
                <Account />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

}
```

The `Navigation` component is as follows:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {App} from "../../../../interfaces/interfaces";
import {map, find, filter} from "lodash";
import NavigationItem from "./NavigationItem";
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

interface NavigationProps {
    applications: App[]
}

const Navigation:React.FC<NavigationProps> = ({applications}: NavigationProps) => {
    const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState<boolean>(false)
    const location = useLocation();
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const activeApplication = find(applications, application => application.url === location.pathname);
    const inactiveApplications = filter(applications, application => application.url !== location.pathname)

    return (
        <div className="flex h-full">
            <div className="z-[2]">
                <NavigationItem application={activeApplication}
                                handleClick={() => setExpanded(expanded => !expanded)}
                                expanded={expanded}
                />
            </div>

            <div className={`flex transform transition transition-transform ${expanded ? 'translate-x-0' : '-translate-x-full'}`}>
                {map(inactiveApplications, application => {
                    return <NavigationItem application={application}
                                           handleClick={() => {
                                               setExpanded(false);
                                               navigate(application.url);
                                           }}
                    />
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Navigation;
```

Thus the `Navigation` component uses the `useLocation` hook from `react-router-dom`.

I want to write some tests for `Header` component and the `header.test.tsx` is as follows:

```
import Header from "./Header";
import {MemoryRouter} from "react-router-dom";

import {describe, it} from "@jest/globals";
import {render, screen} from "@testing-library/react";

describe("<Header/>", () => {
    it("renders the header component with Home link", () => {
        render(<MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/home"]}>
            <Header/>
        </MemoryRouter>);
        const textElement = screen.getByText(/Home/i);
        expect(textElement).toBeInTheDocument();

        const headerElement = screen.getByTestId("header");
        expect(headerElement).toBeInTheDocument()

        // expect(screen.getByRole('link')).toHaveAttribute('href', 'https://www.test.com');
    });
});
```

Thus I wrap the `header` component with `MemoryRouter` but it still gives me an error as follows:

```
useLocation() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.
```

[image]

What do I do wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try 
  ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),

Comment: Is this the only test you are currently running? You don't have any other tests in the suite that might be rendering the `Header` component outside a router? The errors seems to possibly be in some "<Root /> > renders the element with Expert4 value" test case.

Comment: @DrewReese You are right. It was another test with the `Header` component. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your render should look like this

```
render(
<MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/home"]}>
  <Routes>
     <Route path="/home" element={<Header/>} />
  </Routes>
</MemoryRouter>
)
```

Comment: The same error.

Comment: `Routes` and `Route` aren't part of providing a routing context. Only the router component is required.